# How to convert (decode) this url string to the actual word using PHP?

Tags: php

What is the php function to use so as to convert this

```
%25CE%2592%25CE%2595%25CE%259D%25CE%2596%25CE%2599%25CE%259D%25CE%2597
```

to the actual string using PHP?

The actual string is written in Greek characters and it is "ΒΕΝΖΙΝΗ"

Answer (score 0):

Your string is encoded two times.

You can decode it with [`rawurldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php):

```
$str = rawurldecode('%25CE%2592%25CE%2595%25CE%259D%25CE%2596%25CE%2599%25CE%259D%25CE%2597');
// $str = "%CE%92%CE%95%CE%9D%CE%96%CE%99%CE%9D%CE%97"
$str = rawurldecode($str);
// $str = "ΒΕΝΖΙΝΗ"
```